# ThreeJS TextGeometry Undefined b.boundingBox

Tags: three.js

I'm new to Three.JS and I'm following an example from their official documentation on `TextGeometry` (from [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/TextGeometry) ) on how to load a Font and create text from it.

It's failing with the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: b.boundingBox is undefined
```

Here's the code:

```
const fontLoader = new THREE.FontLoader();
        fontLoader.load( "fonts/helvetica.typeface.json", function ( font ) {
            const textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'Hello three.js!', {
                font: font,
                size: 80,
                height: 5,
                curveSegments: 12,
                bevelEnabled: true,
                bevelThickness: 10,
                bevelSize: 8,
                bevelOffset: 0,
                bevelSegments: 5
            } );


            // I added the following lines:
            const textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: FF9900, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
            var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeometry, textMaterial );
            textMesh.position.set(40, 50, 0);
            scene.add(textMesh);
        } );
```

So, what's causing the error? What's missing?

Comment: Your code looks fine at first glance. Does your code work when you try a different `.json` font file?

Comment: @Marquizzo I haven't tried any other `font .json` files. Lemme try and get back to you!

Comment: Yeah that was it. I tried a different font and it's loading properly. (So I guess now I have to get familiar with which fonts are "safe" to use and which aren't...?  Great - another rabbit hole!) Thanks man 

Comment: (Post your comment officially as a proper answer so I can give you credit for it!)